# Ignore Changes on a Specific MultiPage Page

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a MultiPage control on a userform.  I also have a class that detects any changes in textboxes, checkboxes and comboboxes on the whole form.  (Example, if I type or select something, the class detects it and makes a "Save" button visible).

On Page3 of the MultiPage control I have some textboxes.  I do not want the class file to detect changes on this 'tab'.  Is there a way to tell my class to ignore any changes on that page?

EDIT:
Essentially I don't want the below code to run while I'm working on the 3rd tab (page) of the MultiPage control (which resides in my userform)

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents MyTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents MyComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Private WithEvents MyCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Property Set ControlTB(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set MyTextBox = tb
End Property

Public Property Set ControlCB(cb As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set MyComboBox = cb
End Property

Public Property Set ControlCH(ch As MSForms.CheckBox)
    Set MyCheckBox = ch
End Property

Private Sub MyTextBox_Change()
    Call MainCode
End Sub

Private Sub MyComboBox_Change()
    Call MainCode
End Sub

Private Sub MyCheckBox_Change()
    Call MainCode
End Sub

Private Sub MainCode()  

    f_Main.btnUpdateProjectData.Enabled = True
    f_Main.btnUpdateProjectData.Visible = True
    f_Main.Is_Saved = False        

End Sub
```

Comment: Tempted to go with "Sure there's a way", but pretty hard to know that without seeing any of your code. In any case, a yes/no question rarely fares well on this site. What specific problem are you running into, and what would be the minimal code needed to reproduce that issue? See [mcve], then [edit] your post accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon - added class code which handles the multipage control mentioned in the question.